# how to use the nthroot function in R

Tags: r, nth-root

I am trying to use the `nthroot` function from the `pracma` package. 
However, whenever I run it I get an error:

> Error in nthroot(x, 5) : could not find function "nthroot"

I tried installing the `pracma` package but that didn't help either. Could anyone give me any ideas on why this isn't working?

Comment: have you loaded the library before using  the `nthroot` function.
First execute `library(nthroot)`. Alternatively you can try `pracma::nthroot(x, 5)`,

Comment: Sorry if I am missing something obvious, but it sounds like an arbitrary enough function to declare yourself. `nthroot = function(x, n){x^(1/n)}`, `> nthroot(4, 2)
[1] 2`

Comment: @J.G.  Yes, it's easy, but be careful with the sign: nthroot(-8,3) should be -2 , not NaN.

Answer (score 6):

nthroot handles negatives, e.g. returning nthroot(-2,3) == -1.259921, rather than NA

To define this yourself:

```
nthroot = function(x,n) {
  (abs(x)^(1/n))*sign(x)
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with returning -1.26, that's just the real‐valued root. If you're aiming for the *principal* root, the decimal approximation would be around 0.63 + 1.09. No need for `NA` there, `x ^ (1 / n)` is just fine since the real‐valued root is okay here I think.

Comment: Yes, the function I've defined returns -1.26.

I think in some older versions of R, `x^(1/n)` used to return NA or NaN for negative x (see Hans W's comment on the original post) - but I've just checked in v4.0.4 and your solution gives exactly the same answer as mine. So, either solution works nicely :-)

Comment: R version 4.3.0 returns `NaN` for `(-8)^(1/3)` but returns `-2` for `-8^(1/3)`, which is the correct answer. If you use `nthroot = function(x, n){x^(1/n)}`, as JD suggested, this will result in NaNs. The function here is better because it gets around that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Just do

```r
x ^ (1 / n)
```

Where `n` is the root.